# How to create Transparent Hole in Plane in three.js

Tags: three.js

In Three.js, How do I create transparent hole inside a plane so that only objects below the hole are visible. Something like clearRect of canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this with Blender and PSP.
So my scenario is the following:

1. Create a trensparent image with a hole in PS or PSP.
2. Open Blender and create your plane. Use the transparent texture you just created on it.
3. Export the Blender scene into a collada file.
4. Use on of the sample .html-s to display the collada file.

This is my working solution. If you wish I can give you working codes.

Or if you are not familiar with Blender and this collada related things then you should use that example files they using transparent images (for example: webgl_particles_billboards.html).
Take a look at "textures/sprites/disc.png" It's a transparent image as well. You can replace it with your transparent image with the hole.